# How does one show $\Sigma \vdash p$ then $\Sigma \models p$ in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was going through [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf)and wanted to understand proposition 2.2.2 on page 20. Which is:

> If $\Sigma \vdash p$ then $\Sigma \models p$

I understand what it says but the proof eludes me completely because I do not understand how to connect truth/semantics (i.e. mapping to 0 or 1 according to how we label the atoms with a truth function $t:A \to \{0,1 \}$ and (syntactic) provability. The only thing the text says is:

> This should be clear from earlier facts that we stated and which the reader was asked to verify.

However, I have no idea how this suppose to be true at all. Anyone has any ideas how this is done? Why is this suppose to be trivial/obvious? What am I missing/not connecting from what I should know so far?

---

My difficulty is understanding how we actually come up with a model (i.e. a truth assignment) given only that a formal proof $p_1, \dots, p_n$ exists. The only relationship between truth and provability that we know is that the axioms are tautologies (so any truth assignment to them makes them true, always for any entry in the truth table). Being in $\Sigma$ only means you are in that set but nothing else...essentially, I assume we have to be able construct a truth function but thats not clear.

Comment: "My difficulty is understanding how we actually come up with a model (i.e. a truth assignment) given only that a formal proof p1,…,pn exists." That's not what you're trying to do, though: you're trying to show that there **isn't** a model in which $p$ **fails**. That's much easier to think about in this context than showing that there **is** a model in which $p$ **holds** (and indeed just showing that there is some model in which $p$ holds wouldn't show $\Sigma\models p$; you'd need to show that *every* model of $\Sigma$ satisfies $p$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber lol your right. That was a dum confusion. Still I wouldn't know what to do at all since provability is mainly a syntactic/mechanic thing (except for the axioms which I've already shown are tautologies).

Comment: HINT: if its true for some recursively defined structure/set/object, the natural thing is to check if its true using its own inductive definition (proof by induction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is called soundness. You don't need to construct a particular valuation, you need to show that $p$ is true in any valuation that satisfies $\Sigma$ (i.e. any valuation such that all the sentences of $\Sigma$ are true).

You can prove it by induction on the length of the proof. $p$ is the last line of a proof from $\Sigma.$ It is either

1. An axiom instance.
2. A sentence in $\Sigma.$
3. An inference from modus ponens applied two previous lines.

You need to show that $\Sigma\models p.$

1. If $p$ is an axiom, then it is valid, so true in all truth valuations, regardless if they satisfy $\Sigma$. (This assumes you have proven all the axioms are valid previously. If not, do it, it's just a matter of checking their truth tables.)
2. It is obvious that if $p\in\Sigma$ then $\Sigma \models p.$ In any valuation where all sentences in $\Sigma$ are true, $p$ is true, because $p$ is a sentence in $\Sigma.$
3. If we have inferred $p$ from previous lines of the proof $p'$ and $p'\to p,$ we may assume by the induction hypothesis that $\Sigma \models p'$ and $\Sigma \models p'\to p.$ Now let $v$ be any valuation satisfying $\Sigma.$ Then since $\Sigma \models p'$ and $\Sigma\models p,$ we have $v(p')=v(p'\to p)=1.$ Using the truth tables for $\to,$ this implies $v(p)=1.$ Thus, since $v$ was an arbitrary valuation satisfying $\Sigma,$ we have $\Sigma \models p.$

Comment: is "induction on length of proof" same as "structural induction"?

Comment: @Pinocchio It is one of many forms of structural induction.

Comment: It's worth noting that this seems to be assuming a Hilbert-style proof system.  The proof should also be adaptable to a natural deduction style proof system.  For example, in the inductive step for a $\rightarrow I$ proof, suppose we know that $\Sigma, p \models q$.  Then for any truth assignment which makes all statements in $\Sigma$ true, if this truth assignment makes $p$ false, then it also makes $p \rightarrow q$ true.  On the other hand, if it makes $p$ true, then from the assumption $\Sigma, p \models q$, it follows that the truth assignment makes $q$ true also, so it also...

Comment: makes $p \rightarrow q$ true.  In both cases, $p \rightarrow q$ becomes true; so we have shown that $\Sigma \models (p \rightarrow q)$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I always find it hard to understand this style of proof. What exactly is the I.H. and what are your base cases?

Comment: @Pinocchio No base cases (it is a "strong" induction). The induction hypothesis is that $\Sigma \models q$ holds for all previous lines $q$ of the proof.

Comment: @Pinocchio The idea is that the first line of the proof $q_1$is either an axiom or in $\Sigma,$ so $\Sigma \models q_1.$ Same with the second line $q_2.$ The third line $q_3$ is either an axiom, in $\Sigma,$ or the result of applying MP to $q_1$ and $q_2.$ In the first two cases, of course $\Sigma \models q_3,$ and in the third, being that we have already shown $\Sigma\models q_1$ and $\Sigma \models q_2,$ we know that $\Sigma \models q_3$ by the reasoning I gave in the proof. And then you can keep going to the fourth line, etc all the way to $p=q_n.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen in "normal induction" when its strong induction we usually prove $P(0)$ is true and the I.H. is of the form: "$P(k)$ is true for all $k \leq n$. I find it hard to believe there are no base cases...

Comment: @Pinocchio If you show for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb N,$ "if $P(k)$ is true for all $k< n,$ then $P(n)$ is true", you don't need to prove $P(0)$ separately. "$P(k)$ is true for all $k<0$" holds vacuously. (See the second paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction )

Comment: @Pinocchio I would advise convincing yourself of it intuitively, as in my comment above, rather than thinking of it formally as a proof by induction. It will help you get intuition for how structural induction works. Just like induction on $\mathbb N,$ you use the induction hypothesis to iterate forward. My comment also shows why you need no base case to 'get started'. The first two lines are covered cause they can't be from modus ponens. There aren't enough lines yet.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I will try but this is like not intuitive at all for me. Induction used to be intuitive to me until you mentioned that I don't need to prove base cases. If you can be really clear to me about what the induction hypothesis is and the structure of the induction I feel that would help more, perhaps...idk.

Comment: I think what mostly disturbed is the lack of base cases in this new form of induction your teaching me...

Comment: Idk why you call it complete strong induction, case 3) does NOT hold for the first statement in the proof. Since nothing has been proven yet 3) cannot be applied. i.e. the constructor case for the proof only works if we have "atomic/base" building blocks. Maybe there are proofs that don't require base cases, but I don't believe this is one example.

Comment: @Pinocchio Let $q_1,q_2, \ldots q_n$ be the lines of a proof of $p=q_n$ from $\Gamma.$ We want to show that for all $i,$ $\Sigma \models q_i$ (and hence $\Sigma \models p$). My claim is that it is sufficient to prove "If $q_j\models \Sigma $ for all $j < i,$ then $\Sigma \models q_i.$" The proof of my claim: If $\Sigma \not\models q_i$ for some $i,$ then there is a least number $k$ such that $\Sigma \not\models q_k.$ But, then $\Sigma \models q_j$ for all $j<k,$ so by the thing in quotes I claimed was sufficient, $\Sigma \models q_k.$ Contradiction.

Comment: @Pinocchio That said, there is nothing wrong with proving base cases, even if you don't need to prove them. Like, you're free to prove $\Gamma \models q_1$ and $\Gamma \models q_2.$ Your claim about case 3) not holding for the first statement is pure confusion, I think. We are not proving 1), 2), and 3) by induction... they are not claims, just different ways the line $q_i$ could have been derived. We are proving $\Gamma \models q_k$ by induction.

Comment: Why do you say its confusion? Structural induction follows by reasoning about what is true about new things we've constructed from the constructor in this case the constructors builds/constructs a new step of the proof using any of the three steps 1) its an axiom 2) $p \in \Sigma$ 3) MP. Your argument for 1) and 2) happen to be true for any step (including the first step). Step 3) only follows if there is at least 2 more steps previously.

Comment: Also, what is $\Gamma$? We are only talking about the set of proposition in $\Sigma$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen what is the induction hypothesis and the inductive step? I am still having trouble reverse engineering your proof to a format of induction that I can understand.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have been using $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ interchangeably. ($\Gamma$ is my “default” notation for a set of assumptions.)

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that $\Sigma \models q_i$ for all $i <j.$ The thing you must prove under this hypothesis is that $\Sigma \models q_j.$

Comment: “Step 3 only follows if...” “Step 3” is one possible way a given line could have be proven. We are doing a case analysis for the three possible ways and showing in each case, $\Sigma \models q_j.$ If we are on line one (or two) and so could not have used step 3 to prove the line, then this just means we wouldn’t need to take this possibility into account when demonstrating that $\Sigma \models q_1.$

Comment: how did it occur to you that induction was the right thing to do? It just seems it came out of nowhere to me. It feels it would have never occurred to me to do it by induction on length of proofs...any insights?

Comment: @Pinocchio Experience, I guess. When you need to prove something holds for all proofs, the natural thing to do is look at is if it holds for very short proofs, and then see if that extends to longer ones. Induction is the way to make this into a rigorous argument. Same goes for 'all terms' or 'all formulas' or all anything that is recursively defined.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen fantastic insight! Yes, if its true for some recursively defined structure/set/object, the natural thing is to check if its true using its own recursive/inductive definition. Thanks! :D

Comment: what puzzles me still is that propositions are built recursively from connectives and other propositions. How did you know that induction on # of connectives wasn't going to work?

Comment: @Pinocchio Cause you aren't trying to show something about all propositions, you're trying to show something about all proofs (namely that the statement they prove is valid).

Answer (score 0):

We want to show Soundness, i.e. that statements that are provable by our theory $\Sigma$ imply they are true in any model that satisfies our theory. In other words that provable statements only lead to true statements in $\Sigma$.

We will do this by induction on length of proofs. The proof can be done by complete strong induction, but I prefer to write out the whole thing out and explicitly show the base cases.

I will state the induction hypothesis first, for proof of length $n$:

$$ P(n) := \Sigma \vdash p_n \implies \Sigma \models p_n $$

For the base case we want to show $\Sigma \vdash p_1 \implies \Sigma \models p_1$. Thus suppose $\Sigma \vdash p_1$ (now we want to see if we can derive that every model of $\Sigma$ satisfies $p_1$). Thus, $p_1$ is a proof of length 1. Thus, $p_1$ is either a propositional axiom or some statement in our theory:

1. If $p_1$ is a propositional axiom, then its true under every model. In particular its true under every model that satisfies every statement in $\Sigma$ (since any subset works since the whole set works). Thus $\Sigma \models p_1$.
2. If $p_1 \in \Sigma$ then since $p_1$ is part of the theory of $\Sigma$ every model satisfies every statement in $\Sigma$ and so it satisfies this one in particular too. Thus, $\Sigma \models p_1$.

Assume assume strong induction $\forall m(m<n \to P(m))$. Now we want to show that implies $P(n)$. If we want to show $P(n)$ then we want to show $\Sigma \vdash p_n$ implies $\Sigma \models p_n$. Thus we (also) assume $\Sigma \vdash p_n$.

Now there are 3 cases:

1. $p_n$ is a propositional axiom.
2. $p_n \in \Sigma$
3. $p_n$ was arrived via Modus Ponens (MP)

1 and 2 are exactly the same argument as in the base case (and don't need the I.H). The third goes as follows:

3. $p_n$ was arrived via Modus Ponens. Then that means that there were two earlier proposition $p_k$ and $p_{k'} := p_k \to p_n$ in the proof. Since $k < n \land k' < n$ we have by the induction hypothesis that: $ \Sigma \vdash p_k \implies \Sigma \models p_k $ is true and so is $ \Sigma \vdash p_k \to p_n \implies \Sigma \models p_k \to p_n $. Since we assumed they were derived earlier by the proof we also have $\Sigma \vdash p_k$ and $\Sigma \vdash p_k \to p_n$. Thus, we know $\Sigma \models p_k $ and $\models p_k \to p_n $ are valid. Those two statements together give us "semantic Modus Ponens" and therefore we can conclude: $\Sigma \models p_n$ which is what we required.

Thus we have $ \Sigma \vdash p_n \implies \Sigma \models p_n $ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.